# What is the cross-browser way to set a max height on a table?

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have a table where I set the height of the tbody

```
#ml_container table>tbody{ height: 500px; overflow: auto; overflow-x: hidden; }
```

The issue is that when the table has 1 entry, the 1 entry is 500px high in FF3.  I would like the 1 entry to still be 20px (or whatever I specify).  Another issue is that Safari doesn't even recognize this 500px setting so the table has no max height.  I just want a scrollable table that will display 500px high worth of entries at a time.  Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't set a fixed or maximum height on any table elements. [The `height` property is only treated as a minimum height.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#height-layout)

You *can* add `display: block` to your `tbody`. Since it's no longer one of the [`table-*` display types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#table-display) in that case, that *will* make it take the height. However, since the `tbody` is no longer a `table-row-group`, you'll essentially end up with an implicit table inside it again. So any columns in any other `thead`, `tbody` or `tfoot` elements will no longer line up with that scrollable `tbody`.

Apart from the column mismatching, though, this does make it *almost* work in all the latest browsers except IE. You should be able to fix the remaining issues yourself.

I have no idea how to fix it in IE, though. I did come across ["Pure CSS Scrollable Table with Fixed Header"](http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html), but that's rather out-dated, since both of his solutions work in IE6, but break horribly in IE7 and IE8 (in different ways too). They *do* work in IE's Quirks mode, though, so if you desperately need it, that might be your only option.

Answer (score 0):

Thom had the right idea: use javascript. If the window is big enough where the table would be too big, set a fixed manual height on the table/element. :D